# Socio login in Django

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-social-auth

I am trying to build social login in Django, but it is not working fine.

How am doing:

1. Installed python-social-auth
2. added this in INSTALLED_APPS:

   ```
   'social.apps.django_app.default',
   ```
3. Migrated DB (with no errors)
4. Added this in urls.py:

   ```
   url('social-auth/',include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
   ```
5. Got Facebook keys and added this to AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS and keys in settings.py:

   ```
   'social.backends.facebook.Facebook2OAuth2',
   ```
6. Added this to template:

   ```
   <div class="social">
   <ul>
   <li class="facebook"><a href="{% url "social:begin" "facebook"%}">Sign in with Facebook</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   ```

But now when I click on Log in with Facebook, there's an error
 in template rendering : 'social' is not a registered namespace.
I guess this is because social is not present in urls.py.

But adding that dint work.

What more should I do?
thanks

Comment: point 6, this seems to be wrong `href="{% url "social:begin" "facebook"%}"` Can you replace internal or external `"` with `'` and try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In point six replace

```
href="{% url "social:begin" "facebook"%}"
```

with

```
href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook'%}"
```

I think you are running into a problem when the first `"` in `"social:begin"` ends the `"` after `href=`, since `'` and `"` are replaceable you can do this.

Comment: That is in pretty much every programming language, so be aware :)

Comment: The `{% url %}` tag is processed by Django, so it doesn't matter if you use the same quotes for the href and inside the tag. Changing the quotes from `"` to `'` shouldn't make any difference, apart from to make it more readable.

Comment: Then I don't get what else changed that it works now :/

Comment: Btw sachsure next time you can look at the source code of the page, there you can see if any of the `<li class="facebook"><a href="{% url "social:begin" "facebook"%}">Sign in with Facebook</a></li>` is not showing, or it is showing wrong then you can find where is the problem,  since this part of the code results in wierd html.